# How to play a sound when increasing or decreasing the volumne

Tags: sound, 20.04, volume-control

In Ubuntu 18.04, whenever I would increase or decrease the volume, a pop like notification sound would play, with the audio increasing or decreasing in volume - matching the action that I would do.

As in, when I increased the volume, it would play the sound in increasing volume and on decreasing, the sound would play in a decreased volume. This would give me an indication about the level of the volume that I can set (and also verify for me that my speakers are working).

In Ubuntu 20.04, when I increase or decrease the volume, no sound is played. The actual audio does play if I am listening to music or playing a movie, but the sound that is played concurrently to when we increase or decrease the volume is no longer heard.

If it helps, I increase or decrease the volume using the keys on my keyboard (it has special keys).

P.S. The volume does increase or decrease. What I am looking for is the notification audio that plays along with the action

Comment: can your run this command and notice the output? `xmodmap -pke | grep RaiseVolume`

Comment: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.sound event-sounds true`  to see what it is currently set for try `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.sound event-sounds`

Comment: @UnKNOWn It is `keycode 123 = XF86AudioRaiseVolume NoSymbol XF86AudioRaiseVolume`

Comment: @Terrance The output of the second command was `true` - looks like it is set to true already...

Comment: Ok can you run `xev | grep keycode` command in the terminal and then press the VolumeUp and Down buttons in your keyboard and produce the output of the terminal text..

Comment: @UnKNOWn The output: `state 0x10, keycode 36 (keysym 0xff0d, Return), same_screen YES,` and `request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 8, count 248`. The same output for both volume up and volume down keys